# Fetch data record daily

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want Fetch Record selecting a uid same as other uid and display daily starting from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 time and reset the count again when day started,  I dont know how to use time  intervals

This is what I got

```
$uid = $_GET['uid']; 

$query = "SELECT count(*) AS transaction_id from click_tracker WHERE uid=$uid";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{

}
```

This is what I want to happened

for example:
Today count = 150 from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59
and tomorrow starting time again from 00:00:01 count will be back to zero and count again the data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWxj8.png)

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: for example: Today count = 150 from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 and tomorrow starting time again from 00:00:01 count will be back to zero and count again the data

This is what Im looking for buddy

Comment: If your needs are based on each day, I think you don't have to select based on time but on date.

Comment: Yes thanks @ÉderRochaBezerra What I need is on selected user and display their data daily

Comment: uid = 120 
count today =150
and it will reset this count tomorrow, Will be back to zero count when I set to Uid 120 again same as other uid's when I selected them

Comment: you want if uid=120 count today =150 and it will not reset this count for tomorrow,and again start incrementing by 150?

Comment: Nope.. the 150 will be back to zero for a new count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to store the date of insertion, then you can get these records using this:

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) AS transaction_id from click_tracker WHERE uid=$uid
AND InsertionDate=DATE(now())";
```

If you save date and time in a same field you change InsertionDate by `DATE(InsertionDate)=DATE(NOW())`

This will get the count of rows of the specific uid in the current date.

Comment: This is what I did, And it work... Does this reset and bact to zero when time and day change 

$query = "SELECT count(*) AS transaction_id from click_tracker WHERE uid=$uid AND DATE(dateTime)=DATE(NOW())";